Confusion about whether or not an embedded submanifold can be written as $f^{-1}(0)$ for some $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb R$
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, then this post here seems to indicate that embedded submanifolds (that is not an open submanifold) need not be $f^{-1}(0)$ for some smooth function $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb R$, however, this seems to contradict the following statement theorem from Lee:

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, then for any closed $K\subset M$ there is a smooth nonnegative function such that $f^{-1}(0)=K$.

What is going on here? Am I missing something?

Note that 0 is not required to be a regular value for $f$, in contrast to the linked question.

Ok so every submanifold can be written as $f^{-1}(0)$ for some smooth function?

That's what Lee's proposition says, yes.

Every closed subset is the zero level set of some smooth function. The closedness assumption is obviously necessary.
